# What is the best way to connect an MCU with a crystal and its two capacitors?

Tags: microcontroller, crystal

I want to connect an MCU with a crystal and two capacitors. I am unsure what the best way to do that is. I am not talking about how close the crystal should be placed towards the MCU, whether the traces should all be of equal length, or how big the capacitance of the capacitors should be.

Instead I wonder whether the traces from the MCU towards the capacitor should go from the crystal towards the capacitor (see the first picture), from the capacitor to the crystal (second picture), or whether the traces from the MCU should go in the capacitor *and* the crystal (third picture).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're over-worring about this, as long as you: 1) use the schematic shown in the MCU's datasheet 2) use the loading capacitors as suggested from the crystal's datasheet 3) use a crystal that is suggested by the MCU's datasheet or a crystal that is commonly used  then **it will just work**. The frequency of the signals are so low compared to the lengths of your tracks that their length **doesn't matter** as long as they're less than say, 50 mm long. And your tracks are much shorter. So pick the layout you prefer, any of them will work.

Comment: In reality all of those will work fine. BUT, the idea behind that Xtal package is probably that you put one cap from pad 3 to pad 4 so that cap GND is right next to pad 4, and likewise the other cap goes from pad 1 to pad 2 so that the cap GND is near pad 2. There is a school of thought that signal traces should not create acute angles where they meet. You may or may not want to address that.

Comment: Do you care about real-time accuracy in ppm? Then choose C’s and Xtal wisely following examples or just get an XO.

Comment: A wise move is to surround & flood the area with GND, and connect that copper to the GND pin closest to Xtal pins.  Then connect GND from there to other GNDs.  Make it a little Island all to itself only connected to the CPU at one GND point and not connected anywhere else.  The idea is to ensure no currents besides Xtal currents are flowing through Xtal GND, potentially perturbing it.

Comment: Which MCU is this? Most likely it comes with an application note how to best connect the crystal, so knowing which MCU helps to find this.

Answer (score 4):

I would certainly echo the comments here saying it doesnt matter. At, for example, 32MHz, the wavelength is more than 10m, so your tiny trace will make no difference at all from a transmission line impedance perspective. The only thing that could matter, then, is the stray capacitance and inductance. At this scale, you'll be looking at 1-3pF/in, and 10-30nH/in. This means that an extra 3mm of trace makes absolutely no difference. I dont really like layout 3, but I can almost guarantee that there will be no performance difference between it and the other layouts.

As mkeith said, there is some thought that acute trace angles are bad, but I have looked at this a few times and concluded that, as far as I can tell, this is a holdover from many decades ago. If you talk to an RF engineer, they will say it doesnt matter for things under GHz, and you should maybe avoid for PCB fabrication reasons (acid trapping etc), but if you talk to a fabrication person, they will say it makes no difference for that but maybe you should look at it for RF reasons. You can google around to find more info on this if you are interested.

One thing that is important more generally though is that you add a ground plane flood, which will help your circuit in other ways.

Comment: Agree 100%. I avoid acute angles simply because I don't want to get into discussions about it.